# Problem for switching between my operating systems

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, boot-loader

Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my PC along side with my Win 10. First I couldn't choose an OS and I went straight forward to Windows so I did a Boot-Repair on Ubuntu live from this link

I used the following commands just like it said.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Now, when I turn my pc on it goes straight forward to Ubuntu and still no choosing between Win 10 or Linux.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You mentioned a link in your question, but I didn't find one. Please edit your answer to include it.

Comment: Have you also considered putting one of them in virtual-box?